# UITableView performance with many rows

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, uitableview

I have table that handle the device addressBook, that table can have easily 500+ contact.
in addition the table get update every 3 second and then run the code

```
[tableContacts beginUpdates];
[tableContacts reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:arr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableContacts endUpdates];
```

on every update, I update the text on the cell and one image (presence).
all of the calculations for the cell are handles on background thread.
the problem is that most of the time the scrolling is not smooth enough.
and when i touch the table to start scrolling then the scrolling is not responding for 1 second or so(i think because the table is refreshing on this time).

so the question is how to handle very long tables that got data in short time and need to refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way and the right way, but anyway - don't reload rows. Get cells via `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` and change their properties, that's a first. Then, do something about force updates on your table.

What is the actual datasource of your table? Is it `NSFetchedResultsController`? Is it some in-controller `NSArray`? In any case, you should only update cells that have new data. If you use CoreData, use `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods. For `NSArray` I'd suggest KVO - observing for changed objects in array.

Comment: I guess there's a misunderstanding about how `UITableView` works. The method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` always creates a new cell (possibly reusing a recycled one). It never returns the existing table. It's only called by `UITableView`. If you call it yourself, you create a new table cell that's never displayed.

Comment: There's no misunderstanding. Calling `cellForForRowAtIndexPath` outside of tableView create & display cycle gives you a reference for existing cell if the cell was created and displayed. I agree, this needs additional check if given `indexPath` is within `indexPathsForVisibleRows` array. Anyway - how would you update cell's properties from `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods (or any other update methods for that matter) without reloading the row?